# PostgreSQL группировка при изменении значения

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть пример данных:

```
+----------+----+
|time      |temp|
+----------+----+
|1606163169|10  |
|1606163165|0   |
|1606163163|5   |
|1606162384|0   |
|1606161384|0   |
|1606160384|0   |
|1606160380|24  |
|1606160360|10  |
+----------+----+
```

Нужно сделать разбитие на интервалы где значение меняется на 0 на промежуток времени к примеру > 300 секунд

```
+----------+----+-----+
|time      |temp|event|
+----------+----+-----+
|1606163169|10  |3    |
|1606163165|0   |3    |
|1606163163|5   |3    |
|1606162384|0   |2    |
|1606161384|0   |2    |
|1606160384|0   |2    |
|1606160380|24  |1    |
|1606160360|10  |1    |
+----------+----+-----+
```

Смысл в разбитии такой: первое сообщение в 1606160360, temp > 0, это первая группа. Следующее сообщение temp тоже больше нуля, поэтому это будет та же группа.

Затем значение temp = 0, и устанавливается оно на длительное время с 1606160384 по 1606162384. (1606162384 - 1606160384 > 300), значит нужно выделить новую группу (значение temp изменилось на 0 на длительное время).

Следующее сообщение в 1606163163 temp становится больше нуля, значит начинается новая группа, через 2 секунды значение temp становится 0, но только на 4 секунды < 300 по этому для трех сообщений это будет одна и та же группа.

Может есть какие-то мысли? Что-то я в тупике (

Comment: Не очень понятна связь формулировки задачи (весьма, кстати, путаной и невнятной) и показанного результата. Добавьте подробное объяснение для каждого значения event - почему именно от этой записи и именно такое значение.

Comment: внёс дополнения, надеюсь немного понятнее написал

Comment: Задача в общем итерационная - тупо сканируй в заданном порядке, и получишь результат... если  совсем лениться думать - то организуем рекурсивный CTE, где на каждом витке выбираем одну запись, следующую по времени, и анализируем её по отношению к предыдущим. В более сложном случае - прогоняем через gaps and lands, отдельно анализируем нулевые острова на предмет превышения минимально заданного их размера.

Comment: *Затем значение temp = 0, и устанавливается оно на длительное время с 1606160384 по 1606162384. (1606162384 - 1606160384 > 300), значит нужно выделить новую группу (значение temp изменилось на 0 на длительное время).* Непонятно... анализируем именно первый и последний ноль в группе, и пофиг зазор до и после? т.е. два нуля с зазором в секунду, но по 300 секунд пустого интервала до и после - это не группа?

Comment: Анализируется первый ноль и время следующего ненулевого значения, т.е. длительность второй группы, для примера, с 1606160384 включая (первый ноль) по 1606163163 не включая (значение > 0)

Answer (score 0):

Проверяйте:

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS (SELECT "time", 
                temp,
                MAX(temp) OVER (ORDER BY "time" 
                                RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW 
                                  AND 300 FOLLOWING) > 0 "group"
         FROM test),
cte2 AS (SELECT "time", 
                temp,
                CASE WHEN "group" = LAG("group") OVER (ORDER BY "time") 
                     THEN 0
                     ELSE 1 END "group"
         FROM cte1)
SELECT "time",
       temp,
       SUM("group") OVER (ORDER BY "time") "event"
FROM cte2 
ORDER BY "time"
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6b18a786013d5f85e2ed47ce1d7a4ff7)